# question with setting (CreateNew) Quick Action's Record Type

Tags: action

I was hoping to have Quick Action on the Account Object that would create a new Opportunity, and so far all has been going perfectly except for one thing; I was hoping I would be able to set the Quick Action to create a Record based off of the Running User's default Record Type, but it appears that I can only select one for the entire Action.

Use Case/Background Info:

In an effort to make the system as easy to use for our Sales Users as possible, we are attempting to switch how they create Opptys to just clicking a Quick Action from the Account's page.  So far, I've been able to pretty much automate/pre-populate everything with the exception of just a couple fields using predefined values, formulas, and workflows.  We have a rather large "location" picklist containing all of our office locations that we are trying to make a bit easier for the Sales Reps to navigate to find their value.  This field is mandatory off of creation due to an existing integration with another Platform, specific to the industry, who's hard-coded existing infrastructure relies on this field.

We were hoping to use Regional Record Types and Profiles for the Sales Users (basically bucketing East, West, Central, and Mountain together) to trim the Picklist down from 200ish values, to 50 a piece; making navigation for them easier.  (These values aren't easily identifiable at first glance either, think "KTTV", "KTVT", "KVTT", etc.)

It seems that predefined picklist values can't utilize a formula to set the Value, and I can't see a way to set the Record Type to be dynamic; so my question is am I going to have to duplicate my efforts for each region? (i.e. - individual custom Regional Quick Actions, placed on individual custom Regional Page Layouts, assigned to each custom Regional Record Type)  Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a picklist which will be parent and make your main picklist as dependent on parent, in this way you can filter them out.

Otherwise You can create visualforce page for action.